# Next.js Sub-Pages for parameterized routes

Tags: next.js, url-routing

Right now, my routing looks like this:

`https://app.com/users`         opens `pages/users/index.js`
`https://app.com/users/:userid` opens `pages/users/[id].js`

I want to create  route, for example:

`https://app.com/users/:id/friends` -> show all friends for the user
or even
`https://app.com/users/:id/friends/:friendId` -> show a specific friend

I have tried

```
pages
    users
        index.js
        [id].js
        friends
            index.js
            [friendId].js
```

but i can only reach `users/friends` and not `users/:id/friends``

How do i set my `pages` directory so i can use this sort of routing?

Also, I want to be able to access id and friendId in the context of getServerSideProps...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't get the answer description well, pls follow the diagram I made.

If you want this `https://app.com/users/:id/friends`, then you should create something like this:

`pages/users/index.js/[id]/index.js/friends.js`

So to make this clear, you have a folder name `pages` (where all pages folder and files are), then you have a `user` folder (this takes an `index.js` which means user path). Now in the `user` folder, you have to create a folder named `[id]`, in this folder you should create a file name `index.js`, this index.js stand for the `:id`. The last thing is to create the friend.js in the `[id]` folder.

Something like this.

```
pages ----------------- Main folder
    users ------------- A folder inside `pages` folder  
       index.js ------- A file inside `users` folder == `https://app.com/users`
       [id] ----------- A folder inside `users` folder
          index.js ---- A file inside `[id]` folder ==`https://app.com/users/:id`
          friends.js -- A file inside `[id]` folder == `https://app.com/users/:id/friends`
```

If you want something like this `https://app.com/users/:id/friends/:friendId`

Then you will have to do something like this:

```
pages ------------------------- Main folder
    users --------------------- A folder inside `pages` folder  
       index.js --------------- A file inside `users` folder == `https://app.com/users`
       [id] ------------------- A folder inside `users` folder
          index.js ------------ A file inside `[id]` folder ==`https://app.com/users/:id`
             [friends] -------- A folder inside `[id]` folder
                index.js ------ A file inside `[friends]` folder
                friendId.js --- A file inside `[friends]` folder
```

Comment: Thanks, this sounds about right. I'll try it out when i have the chance

Comment: Okay nice.  Always have in mind that:
1. `index.js` file will be the name of its parent folder.
2. `[id].js` files will always stand for a parameter, you can use any name not only id. ----------/:id
3. An `index.js` file inside `[id]` folder will stand for the `[id]` folder name while any other file in the `[id]` folder will be its parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dynamic Routing syntax in your folders instead of a file in order to nest them (create a folder [id] instead of a file [id].js). For your specific example it would look like this:

```
pages
    users
       index.js
       [id]
          friends
               [friendId].js
```